# Generate Script wizard scripting schema and data to ignore "GO"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am using SSMS Generate Scripts wizard to script the schema and data for few tables in my database. Somehow the end result will add "GO" after certain insert script.

Is there any way to prevent SSMS adding "GO" from the generated script?

Thanks,

Comment: I can't find an option to control that. Since you are only scripting a few tables, could you use Find/Replace to get rid of them? Are they causing a problem?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, yes, I could do that, but I was automating the script with Powershell, a kind of export/import and the GO is breaking it.

Answer (score 4):

Option "Delimit individual statements" is available in General scripting options (Tools -- Options -- SQL Server Object Explorer -- Scripting). [SSMS Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQCzu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the option but ended up using a powershell script to clean it up

```
(Get-Content -Path $fileName) | Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'GO' } | Set-Content -Path $fileName
```

Comment: If you script using SMO in powershell, you can set the [`ScriptBatchTerminator` scripting option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions) to false.